# How can I create an Apache POI Pivot using another workbook as data source?

Tags: apache-poi, pivot-table

How can I create an Apache POI Pivot using another workbook as data source?
AreaReference doesn't admit a workbook as parameter, but only sheetName.

```
/** Data source sheet */
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet dataSourceSheet = wb.createSheet("dataSourceSheet");

CellReference position = new CellReference(0, 0, true, true);
AreaReference source = new AreaReference(
                       new CellReference("dataSourceSheet", 0, 0, true, true),
                       new CellReference("dataSourceSheet", 100, 100, true, true),
                       null);
            
/** Pivot */
XSSFWorkbook wbPivot = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet pivotSheet = wbPivot.createSheet("myPivot");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(source, position); /* ???? */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing what `apache poi` provides up to now. It can be done if one knows what `Excel` stores in that case.

The main principle of creating pivot tables is the same. The difference is that the pivot cache's worksheet source additional contains a `rId` which refers to a external relationship to the source workbook. So the additional task is to create that external relationship to the source workbook and to set that `rId` to the worksheet source of pivot cache.

The following code shows how to do this:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataConsolidateFunction;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.TargetMode;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreatePivotTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String[] headers = new String[] { "Company", "Status", "Counter" };
  Object[][] sheetData = {
   {"Company 1", "OK", "x"},
   {"Company 1", "NOK", "x"},
   {"Company 2", "NOK", "x"},
   {"Company 1", "OK", "x"},
   {"Company 3", "OK", "x"},
   {"Company 1", "NOK", "x"},
  };

  //File sourceWorkbookFile = new File("C:/Users/axelr/Documents/PivotData.xlsx");
  //File pivotWorkbookFile = new File("C:/Users/axelr/Documents/PivotTable.xlsx");
  File sourceWorkbookFile = new File("PivotData.xlsx");
  File pivotWorkbookFile = new File("PivotTable.xlsx");
  
  // creating source workbook  
  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(sourceWorkbookFile) ) {

   XSSFSheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");
   XSSFRow row;
   XSSFCell cell;
   int r = 0;
   row = dataSheet.createRow(r++);
   int c = 0;
   for (String header : headers) {
    cell = row.createCell(c++);
    cell.setCellValue(header);
   }
   for (Object[] dataRow : sheetData) {
    row = dataSheet.createRow(r++);
    c = 0;
    for (Object value : dataRow) {
     cell = row.createCell(c++);
     if (value instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)value);
     } //else if...
    }
   } 
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
  
  // creating pivot workbook  
  try (XSSFWorkbook sourceWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(sourceWorkbookFile));
       XSSFWorkbook pivotWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(pivotWorkbookFile) ) {
           
   XSSFSheet dataSheet = sourceWorkbook.getSheet("Data");
   XSSFSheet pivotSheet = pivotWorkbook.createSheet("Pivot");

   AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(
    new CellReference(0, 0),
    new CellReference(dataSheet.getLastRowNum(), dataSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()-1),
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);
   
   XSSFPivotCacheDefinition pivotCacheDefinition = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition();
   String rId =  pivotCacheDefinition.getPackagePart().addRelationship( 
    sourceWorkbookFile.toURI(), 
    TargetMode.EXTERNAL, 
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath")
    .getId();
   pivotCacheDefinition.getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheSource().getWorksheetSource().setId(rId); 

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 2);

   pivotWorkbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

This code is tested and works using current `apache poi` versions `4.1.2` and `5.0.0`.

Comment: Your solution work well with XSSFWorkbook; but i need to use stream workbook "SXSSFWorkbook".
I notice that it doesn't seem to work with these:
SXSSFWorkbook swb = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb); /* cause I need to manage huge datas */
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(sourceWorkbookFile);
swb.write(fileOut); /* ...  and close the file. */
XSSFWorkbook sourceWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(sourceWorkbookFile);

In defining "AreaReference" with dataSheet for "pivotSheet.createPivotTable(...)" it doesn't work.
Do you have any solution?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Stefano: Sorry, but no. In my eyes is using `SXSSFWorkbook` a dead end. It simply is not possible to stream content into a `*.xlsx` file. One might be able streaming content into the single `XML` files but keeping the relationships between those files intact while streaming is nearly impossible. So I will not bothering myself with this.